# Why can I not have a struct with a member named "refresh" when using ncurses?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, ncurses

I'm making an ncurses application, and I've come accross something that's puzzling.

If you have a struct with a member named "refresh" that is a function pointer, and you call that function later, you will get the following compile-time error:

```
main.c:20:10: error: ‘Point’ has no member named ‘wrefresh’
     point.refresh();
```

Here's a little test you can try to compile:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

typedef struct PointStruct Point;

void Point_refresh() {

}

struct PointStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
    void (*refresh)();
};

int main() {
    Point point;
    point.x = 0;
    point.y = 0;
    point.refresh = &Point_refresh;
    point.refresh();
}
```

That will give you the error mentioned above. However, if you take out the first line that includes ncurses, it will compile with no issues.

What is the reason that this does not work with ncurses, and is there a way around it? It's not really a big deal, just a slight annoyance that I have to rename that member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `refresh()` is a "pseudo-function" `#define`d by curses as a macro for `wrefresh(win)`, so the preprocessor is going to replace all occurrences of that word in your source. There's no sensible way round it other to `#undef` it, and always use `wrefresh()` instead.

Comment: There is another way around it: put parentheses around the function name.

Comment: That's a cure worse than the disease, I think.

Comment: Probably less pointless than having to remember to use parentheses every single time you call it to avoid having to remember to give it a different name once. As for "undefining a useful macro" being "idiotic", the C standard recommends doing just that in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
 point.refresh();
```

With:

```
(point.refresh)();
```